# Java Matrix using Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I'm struggling to find an answer to the problem below. User inputs rows and columns. Example below is given for 4 x 4 matrix.

1 8 9 16

2 7 10 15

3 6 11 14

4 5 12 13

I cannot find how to relate the numbers when printing the array. The only obvious relation is how it goes downwards and upwards. From my perspective looks really hard. I'm just a beginner.

Not quite sure if there is any point to post the code, but it's just the basic lines:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your array rows: ");
    int rows = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter your array columns: ");
    int columns = scanner.nextInt();

    int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];

    int counter = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            counter++;
            array[i][j]=...(stuck at the beginning);
        }
```

Probably I'd need to use several loops , not only the above-mentioned or probably it is totally wrong ...
Thank you in advance!

Comment: you should store it row-wisely, array[0][0] = 1; array[1,3] = 15; array[2][1]=3

Comment: Yes, sorry. I noticed I reversed them. Should be rows then columns. But still need help for it.

Comment: Must be a class going on. Here are now **7** questions created in the last hour exactly like this one.

Comment: That would be funny if they were related :)

Comment: from where the number 1 8 9 16

2 7 10 15

3 6 11 14

4 5 12 13 come from?

Comment: User manually inputs rows and columns count. Matrix should start from 1.

Comment: @user3633880 feel free for any queries.

Comment: Thank you,Dante! I saw you answered using columns first and then rows. Is there any way to do it by using rows first ? Or the idea to check rows will make it harder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it.

```
    int counter = 0;
    boolean top_to_bottom=true;
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            counter++;
            if(top_to_bottom)
             array[i][j]=counter;
            else
             array[rows-1-i][j]=counter;
        }
        if(top_to_bottom)
         top_to_bottom=false;
        else top_to_bottom=true;
    }
```

Comment: Great ! Thank you! So actually in the 'for' statement it has to be columns first, then rows ?

Answer (score 0):

It serves the purpose

import java.util.*;

public class Seq

{

public static void main(String[] args)

{

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter your array rows: ");

int rows = scanner.nextInt();

```
System.out.println("Please enter your array columns: ");
```

int columns = scanner.nextInt();

```
 int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];

  int counter = 0;
```

for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++){

if(j%2==0)
    {

```
 for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
     {
        counter=counter+1;
            array[i][j]=counter;

        }
 } 
else

 {
      for (int i = rows-1; i >=0; i--) 

          {
                counter=counter+1;

                array[i][j]=counter;

            }
     }

  }

  for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)

    {

        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++)
      {

        System.out.print(array[i][j]+" ");

        }
        System.out.println();
         }
   }
```

}